# Using mutex to enforce single instance

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am using mutex object in order to enforce single instance.
On Win 7 I the code is not working. What might be the reason?
Code is here

```
//Test for another instance
HANDLE hMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, TRUE, 
      _T("Global\\DFFDFD-C1733E55-A6FD-47D5-8638-053E938E08B8"));
    if ( hMutex )
    {
       if( GetLastError() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS )
       {
          DebugWrite(_T("Another instance of application running. Aborting.\n"));  
          MessageBeep( 0xFFFFFFFF );
          ShowErrorMessage(IDS_ANOTHER_INSTANCE_RUNNING_ABORTING);
          CloseHandle( hMutex );
          return 0;
       }
    }
```

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: Not working means that the mutex created multiple times hence the application may be opened multiple times concurrently

Comment: How do you know the mutex was created? You never check the return value of `CreateMutex`.

Comment: Actually I do. I will fix the sample code

Comment: As currently written, the sample code does not distinguish between failure and success, other than the special case where an existing mutex is successfully opened.  Are you really sure that multiple copies of the mutex are being *successfully* created?  Perhaps you could post a complete, working program demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you attach Global\ before your mutex object name, it means this mutex is accessible to all users on the computer.

Although if you are on a vista or win7 computer you still have problems because a mutex created by an elevated application will not be accessible to a non-elevated application.

To overcome this problem you can assign a SecurityDescriptor as the first parameter of createmutex function with allow access to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this code doesn't work either, because `CreateMutex` will return not NULL handle for the Mutex even if it already exists.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682411.aspx):

> If the mutex is a named mutex and the object existed before this function call, **the return value is a handle to the existing object**, GetLastError returns ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS".

And this code checking first for hMutex to be not NULL

Comment: I used this code in order to enforce single instance run.  After I added security identifier to the code it worked fine. But scenario when I fail to create or get access to mutex so handle is zero is actually another bug. I changed code to take care of this.